# UITableView Cell highlight / retain selected value IOS

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7, highlight

I have `UIView`(LeftMenu) with `UITableView (UITableViewStylePlain)`. I have around 7 controllers , Where on selection of each cell I wanna push corresponding controller. I tried custom highlight for cell with yellow color as below ,

```
  UIColor *yel=[[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:240/255.0 green:197/255.0 blue:67/255.0 alpha:1.0];
  UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
  [bgColorView setBackgroundColor:yel];
  [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
```

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. But I am unable to retain selected cell If I move to next controller. In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` , I am capturing last selected index ( When I select new cell , old should be unhighlighted). But it seems , If I make custom its not retaining. If I keep `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone` , `cell.backgroundColor` it works. But not highlighting :(

```
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:indexPath.row forKey:@"SSLastSelectedLeftMenuIndex"];
```

I am initializing `UIView`(LeftMenu) with frame.

Issue : Gray Color on Highlight after few mins custom yellow highlight coming and Not retaining selected cell color.

I know I am missing some silly thing. But its eating my time. Advance thanks :)

**Update:-**
below is my `-cellForRowAtIndexpath` method

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:@"SSLastSelectedLeftMenuIndex"]==indexPath.ro‌w)
{
    ///<HIGHLIGHT CODE>;
}
```

Comment: what is your issue exactly? Do you want to select the UITableView multiple rows??

Comment: @Meenu Let me get things straight when you come back to the UIView(LeftMenu) you want the last selected row in tableView to be selected, right

Comment: Yes , I need that. Also , If I do cell select , It highlights with Gray color though i am using custom cell. :(

Comment: @Meenu post your cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to select the last selectd cell .. (try)

```
- (void)viewWillAppear
   {
       [uper viewWillAppear];

       //hear u can set the selected cell
       //get indexpath of row
       int k = your saved row
       NSIndexPAth *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:k];//if u hav single section or u can use other class method
      [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:_selctedIndex animated:NO scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionNone];//hear u are directly setting the last selected cell once view will appear

   }
```

hop this helps u :)

if u are using UITableViewCell then u do something like this,for yellow color for selecting the cell

```
     //in controller do like this
     - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
        if(cell == nil)
        {
           cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

          UIColor *yel=[[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:240/255.0 green:197/255.0 blue:67/255.0 alpha:1.0];
          UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
         [bgColorView setBackgroundColor:yel];
         [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];

       }

      return cell;

   }
```

in the subclassed table cell there is one method, to display yellow color for selecting the cell

```
  //in CustomCell.m
  //in the custom cell set the color for selected state
  //override this method
   - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
   {
        [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

         // Configure the view for the selected state
         if(selected)
         {
             //same code of urs
             UIColor *yel=[[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:240/255.0 green:197/255.0 blue:67/255.0 alpha:1.0];
             UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];//for entaire cell,set the frame
             [bgColorView setBackgroundColor:yel];
             [self setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
         }
     }
```

Comment: I dint subclass tableviewcell. Is that mandatory for my need?

Comment: Still gray color highlight is coming :(

Comment: @Meenu try with subclassing the cell

Comment: Wow Great its working good. Now ,the issue is when I select new cell ,  old one is not getting unhighlighted :(

Comment: @Meenu rite now i am in home, just try becz i didnt hav mac in home thats wy, since u are storing the selected "SSLastSelectedLeftMenuIndex" in user defaults, just set the last selected cell in "viewWillAppear method" see my updated answer sorry if cant provide exact answer, i wil help u tomoro :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44895/discussion-between-shan-and-meenu)

Comment: come to chat if u are online

Comment: u can put else condition "setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated" for deselected cell there by u can set default color for deselected cell

Comment: put a property in custom cell that is "@property (nonatominc, assign) int index;" assign the value in the cell for index method at the end cell.index = indexPath.row; use this in custom cell

Comment: come to chat .. if u are there

Comment: u can leave a comment when u are online

Answer (score 0):

You have misunderstood selection and highlighting a cell you should change your cellForRowAtIndexPath like below to select the previously selected item.

before that Declare a globle variable _selctedIndex of type NSIndexpath to store the last selected cell

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        UIColor *yel=[[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:240/255.0 green:197/255.0 blue:67/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        [bgColorView setBackgroundColor:yel];
        [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];

    }
    if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:@"SSLastSelectedLeftMenuIndex"]==indexPath.row)
    {
        //<HIGHLIGHT CODE>;
        _selctedIndex=indexPath;   //code Updated
    }
return cell;
}
```

After your tableView has reloaded call the below line of code

```
[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:_selctedIndex animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
    }
```

The UITableViewCell class will assign the view you have mentioned to the property selectedBackgroundView instead of the Default blue color view for showing in the background when a cell is selected

Comment: Its not working same issue still happening vignesh. The problem is why Gray color highlight is coming though we are doing custom cell highlight? what this should be cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;???

Comment: @Meenu did you subClassed UITableViewCell

Comment: But now issue is , When I select new cell , selected one not getting unhighlighted :(

Comment: @Meenu while did you store the selected index in NSUserDefaults in -didSelectRowAtIndex

Comment: Vignesh , Yes I do store selected index in NSUserDefaults . Its not working.
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:@"SSLastSelectedLeftMenuIndex"]==indexPath.row)
{[cell setSelected:YES animated:YES];}

Comment: but its still retaining..... responding late after i entered into viewcontroller :(

Comment: FYI: I am subclassing UITableViewCell and doing changes in setHighlighted

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same problem in a project, when tapping on a cell long enough to engage highlight then moving to a scroll the UITableView holds onto the highlighted index somehow so that the next attempt to select uses that previous indexPath.

To resolve I did the following

Add Property to Track Offending indexPath

```
...
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSIndexPath *cachedPath;
...
```

Track indexPath with didUnhighlightRowAtIndexPath

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didUnhighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.cachedPath = indexPath;
}
```

On Drag reload offending indexPath

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (self.cachedPath)
    {
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[self.cachedPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }
    self.cachedPath = nil;
}
```

For good measure clear the property on selection

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.cachedPath = nil;
}
```